Finnish and Hungarian loanword cognates?
Finnish and Hungarian are two distantly related, mutually unintelligible languages in Europe that do not belong to the Indo European language family but the Uralic one. But they do have one more thing in common: they both have taken loanwords from Germanic and Slavic sources. If I recall correctly, Finnish's words are mostly Germanic and Hungarian's are mostly Slavic.
Are there any words in Finnish and Hungarian that are derived from the same Proto Germanic or Proto Slavic roots? If so, how many are there and what are the most notable words? I don't know if there are, given it may take a lot of borrowed words to create even a few overlapping words. However, I think there could be a handful hiding in the languages, even if they are "false friends".

When I say "Finnish's words are mostly Germanic and Hungarian's are mostly Slavic" I mean out of loanwords from those 2 families just to be 100% clear.

Just to be clear, you’re looking for words that Finnic (so Finnish, Estonian, Ingrian, Karelian, etc.) have borrowed from Germanic, where Hungarian has borrowed a cognate word from Slavic – correct? Or are you also including, for example, the same word being borrowed from Germanic into both Finnic and Hungarian?

I said Finnish, not Finnic in general. I mean the same word from either family being borrowed into both Finnish and Hungarian.

If you mean directly borrowed into Finnish specifically, as opposed to Proto-Finnic (and thence the Finnic languages), then that automatically leaves out half of the question: Proto-Germanic broke up into daughter languages/branches long before Late Proto-Finnic diverged into the attested Finnic languages (including Finnish), so Finnish and Proto-Germanic never coexisted. Any loans from Proto-Germanic would have to be into Proto-Finnic. If you include later Germanic/Slavic languages, that changes, of course, but then English words borrowed into Finnish and Hungarian become the obvious answer.
